# How to calculate the sum of a TextBox from another TextBox in C#

Tags: c#

I want get values is integer number in `textbox`.

But I don't know how to convert my `textbox1.text` to `int` type.

It exception error like:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'

My code like:

`txtTo.Text = Convert.ToInt32(txtFrom.Text) + listViewItem1.Items.Count;`

Comment: Have you searched for this error message here on StackOverflow?

Comment: Just slap a `.ToString()` on after the statement

Comment: The question's actually a bit contradictory; you say first that you want to convert a string to an int, but the error shows that you're trying to convert an int to  a string. Looks like you got it sorted, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is simple to fix, just add a ToString to the result of the addition

```
txtTo.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txtFrom.Text) + listViewItem1.Items.Count).ToString();
```

but this is a partial solution because, if your user types something that is not a valid integer number, the conversion to Int32 will fail.

You need to use Int32.TryParse

```
int num;
if(!Int32.TryParse(txtFrom.Text, out num))
{
  MessageBox.Show("Not a valid number");
  return;
}
txtTo.Text = (num + listViewItem1.Items.Count).ToString();
```

Comment: I set in textbox user must type numeric. Thanks your option.

Comment: Better use a defensive approach with user input. There are many ways to insert invalid text (for example pasting from the Clipboard is usually difficult to catch)

Answer (score 3):

```
txtTo.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(txtFrom.Text) + listViewItem1.Items.Count).ToString();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//to get the int value of the textbox
txtTo.Text = int.Parse(textFrom.Text);
//to get the int value of the sum of the text box value 
//added to the count of listview1 items count value
txtTo.Text = int.Parse(textFrom.Text) + listViewItem1.Items.Count; 
//to get the value of the textbox as a string
txtTo.Text = int.Parse(textFrom.Text).ToString(); 
//to get the value of the sum of the text box value added to the count of listview1 items count value as a string
txtTo.Text = (int.Parse(textFrom.Text) + listViewItem1.Items.Count).ToString();
```